# PyQT QThread follow the thread execution order (wait)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, python-multithreading

I'm trying to run a few slow processes but, I need to keep updated the QDialog to show the progress (maybe I put a progress bar too).

So I decide to use QThread, but on the first try, it doesn't work as I expected.

In my example code:
1- I'm using a simple ping to my default gateway
2- I'm pinging to my dns resolver

As you can see on imagem below, the information is showed according the thread is finalizing, but it is a mess to me.

Is possible to respect the threads order to show the informations?

Thanks.

[image: example]

Follow my example code:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from ping3 import ping, verbose_ping
import socket
import dns.resolver

class ExternalTests(QThread):
    data_collected = pyqtSignal(object)
    
    def __init__(self, title, arg=None):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.title = title
        self.arg = arg

    def run(self):
        resp = ping(self.arg)
        self.data_collected.emit('%s: %s' % (self.title, resp))

class MainMenu(QMenu):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMenu.__init__(self)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #3a80cd; color: rgb(255,255,255); selection-color: white; selection-background-color: #489de4;")
        # Diagnostics
        self.check_internet = QAction("Diagnosys")
        self.check_internet.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("..\\img\\lupa.png")))
        self.check_internet.triggered.connect(self.diagnosticNetwork)
        self.addAction(self.check_internet)
        self.addSeparator()

        # To quit the app
        self.quit = QAction("Quit")
        self.quit.triggered.connect(app.quit)
        self.addAction(self.quit)

    def diagnosticNetwork(self):
        self.check_internet_dialog = QDialog()
        self.check_internet_dialog.setWindowTitle("Check external connections")
        self.check_internet_dialog.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
        self.check_internet_dialog.setGeometry(150, 100, 700, 500)

        # text box
        self.textbox = QTextBrowser(self.check_internet_dialog)
        self.textbox.move(20, 20)
        self.textbox.resize(660,400)
        self.textbox.setFont(QFont("Courier New", 12))
        self.textbox.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")

        #button copy
        btn_copy = QPushButton("Copy", self.check_internet_dialog)
        btn_copy.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("..\\img\\copy.png")))
        btn_copy.move(520,450)
        btn_copy.clicked.connect(self.dialogClickCopy)

        #button close
        btn_copy = QPushButton("Close", self.check_internet_dialog)
        btn_copy.setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap("..\\img\\close.png")))
        btn_copy.move(605,450)
        btn_copy.clicked.connect(self.dialogClickClose)
    
        # tests
        self.textbox.setTextColor(QColor("white"))
        self.textbox.append("Diagnosys")
        self.textbox.append("--------------------------------------------------")
        self.textbox.setTextColor(QColor("cyan"))
        
        self.threads = []
        #QCoreApplication.processEvents()
        
        ''' ping default gateway '''
        ping_default_gw = ExternalTests("default gatewat is reacheble", "192.168.0.1")
        ping_default_gw.data_collected.connect(self.onDataReady)
        self.threads.append(ping_default_gw)
        ping_default_gw.start()
        
        ''' ping dns resolver '''
        ping_dns_resolvers = dns.resolver.Resolver().nameservers
        for dns_resolver in ping_dns_resolvers:
            ping_dns_resolver = ExternalTests("dns resolver is reacheble %s" % dns_resolver, dns_resolver)
            ping_dns_resolver.data_collected.connect(self.onDataReady)
            self.threads.append(ping_dns_resolver)
            ping_dns_resolver.start()

        self.check_internet_dialog.exec_()

    
    def onDataReady(self, data):
        print(data)
        if data:
            self.textbox.append(data)
        else:
            self.textbox.append("error")


    def dialogClickCopy(self):
        pass

    def dialogClickClose(self):
        self.check_internet_dialog.close()

class SystemTrayIcon(QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, menu, parent=None):
        QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self)
        self.setIcon(QIcon("..\\img\\icon.png"))
        self.setVisible(True)
        self.setContextMenu(menu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication([])
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
    app.setApplicationName('pkimonitor')      
    app.setApplicationVersion('0.1')
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("..\\img\\icon.png"))
    menu = MainMenu()
    widget = QWidget()
    trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(menu, widget)
    trayIcon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The "thread execution order" is respected, in the form of their *execution* (and finalization). Since a non resolving ping can take more time, I'd say it's perfectly normal that its threads replies *after* the other. If you want to respect some form of "order", you should collect all data and *then* show the output as soon as they are all completed, or after some timeout, but that has nothing to do with the execution order.

Comment: I agree with you. I understand that one process may take longer than the other, but as they are being executed in parallel, it will end up showing the result of the thread that ended first. The problem is that I don't know how to wait for the previous one to execute the next one.

Comment: There are various possibilities, and it's up to you to choose the one that fits your needs. A possible solution could be to create an unique identifier for each thread, emit that id along with the result, and use an internal "check list" to wait until all threads have replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create a scheme to organize by "run position" and it works. Follow my code.

In 'diagnosticNetwork':

```
self.data_list = []
self.data_hold = []
```

In 'onDataReady':

```
if len(self.data_list) > 0:
    if self.data_list[-1][0] + 1 == data[0]:
        self.data_list.append(data)
        if data[2]:
            self.textbox.append("%s: %s" % (data[1], 'OK'))
        else:
            self.textbox.append("%s: %s" % (data[1], 'NOK'))
    elif self.data_list[-1][0] < data[0]:
        self.data_hold.append(data)
else:
    self.data_list.append(data)
    if data[2]:
        self.textbox.append("%s: %s" % (data[1], 'OK'))
    else:
        self.textbox.append("%s: %s" % (data[1], 'NOK'))

if len(self.data_hold) > 0:
    hold_sorted = self.data_hold[:]
    hold_sorted.sort()
    for line_hold in hold_sorted:
        if self.data_list[-1][0] + 1 == line_hold[0]:
            if line_hold[2]:
                self.textbox.append("%s: %s" % (line_hold[1], 'OK'))
            else:
                self.textbox.append("%s: %s" % (line_hold[1], 'NOK'))
            self.data_list.append(line_hold)
            del self.data_hold[0]
```

I worked with two lists, data_list and data_hold. The results that I received from the threads, I filled out the main list according to the order that I pre-established, if the result that entered was not the next one in the sequence, it goes to data_hold, then scan this list to fill the rest of my textbox.

Thank you for all help!